# Raster::focal function replaces edge cells with NA values

Tags: raster

I am trying to use raster::focal to find out how many neighbors of value 1 each raster cell has. However, I have noticed that in the resulting raster the edge cells have been replaced with NA values. How can I get neighbor counts for the outer edge of the raster?

Here is a reproducible example:

```
#create raster and add 1's and 0's
land <- raster(matrix(0, 8, 10), xmn=408027.5, xmx=413027.5, ymn=4370000, 
ymx=4374000)
land[4:8, 2:5] <- 1
land[2:3, 8:9] <- 1
land[1,0:10] <- 1
land[is.na(land[])] <- 0
#plot the raster
plot(land)
```

[image: raster]

```
#create window for focal function
w <- matrix(1,3,3)
#run raster::focal
land.foc <- focal(land, w=w, fun=sum)
#plot resulting focal raster
plot(land.foc)
```

[image: focal]

```
#plot NA values in land.foc
plot(is.na(land.foc))
```

[image: edge NAs]

However, as you can see when you compare the two rasters, the outer-most cells in the focal raster have been replaced with NA's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to set `pad=TRUE` and `padValue=0`. This 'extends' your raster and adds virtual rows and columns with you `padValue`, in this case 0.

```
land.foc <- focal(land, w=w, fun=sum,pad=T,padValue=0)

plot(land.foc)
```

[image]

```
plot(is.na(land.foc))
```

[image]

#### Edit:

Another way of looking at it is that the virtual cells don't have *any* values, they are `NA`.

So instead of assigning `0` as `padValue`, just add `na.rm=TRUE` to your call.

If you really need to do something else with the virtual cells, you can create your own function, which handles the NA cells more specific, that you then pass into focal.

Comment: Thank you! This partially solves the issue. However, is there a way to customize padValue so that each edge cell receives the value of the closest non-edge cell? Giving a standard value to all edge cells isn't quite what I was looking for.

Comment: @CarriePerkins given that you sum occurrences, wouldn't using anything else than 0 give you skewed results? The pad cells don't actually exist ...

Comment: @CarriePerkins reading your comment again - the edge cells don't get the padValue, rather the virtual neighbors of the edge.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't phrase my comment very well. I meant that by giving the virtual neighbors a value of 0, the edge cells in the raster end up having less neighbors than they might have had if the virtual neighbors had a value of 1, for example. Is there a way to assign values to the virtual neighbors based on the values of the edge cells nearest to them?

Comment: @CarriePerkins No I understood, but my question is: Given that the virtual neighbors _don't_ exist, wouldn't the edge cells in the raster end up having more neighbors than they should if the virtual neighbors have 1?

Comment: I see what you mean. But say for example the raster represents islands (value 1) and water (value 0). If cells of value 1 are edge cells it is likely that there are more land cells close by that are cut off by the extent of the raster. It would then seem more appropriate to assign the virtual neighbors of these edge cells a value of 1. For that reason I just wonder if there is a way to assign values to virtual neighbors based on the value of the nearest edge cell to them...

Comment: @CarriePerkins See my previous edit. There's no built-in functionality in `focal` for what you want. You probably need to create a user defined function to pass into focal. But this already exceeds the scope of your original post IMHO.