# Binary raster aggregation with custom function produces NA at boundary cells

Tags: r, aggregate, raster

I have a huge `RasterLayer` of urban/non-urban classification at 500m*500m resolution, which I am trying to aggregate using a custom function. Urban cells have the value 1, while non-urban cells have the value 0. The data has no NAs, but has over 70M elements (which is why I can't post an example; not sure if a randomly generated matrix would produce the same issue either).

When I use `raster::aggregate()` with the function given below (I want new cells to be classified as "urban" if at least 25% of the original cells are urban), the new `RasterLayer` contains NA values at the boundaries/edges of urban areas. `rast1` is my original raster and `rast2` is the aggregated one.

```
library(tidyverse)

# aggregate function
rast_agg_fn <- function(x, ...){
  if_else(sum(x == 1) >= 0.25*length(x), 1, 0) # 25% threshold
}

# 10km*10km
rast2 <- rast1 %>% 
  raster::aggregate(fact = 20, fun = rast_agg_fn)
```

The raster data is for India and when I overlay `rast2` on a map using `leaflet`, it is evident that the boundaries are NAs.

```
library(leaflet)

leafcols <- colorFactor(c(NA, "#0C2C84"), values(rast2),
                         na.color = "#ffba00")

leaflet() %>% 
  addTiles() %>% 
  addRasterImage(rast2, 
                 colors = leafcols,
                 opacity = 0.7,
                 maxBytes = 100 * 1024 * 1024) %>% 
  addLegend(pal = leafcols, values = values(rast2))
```

[image]

Although the function should be aggregating such boundary cells using the 25% threshold, it is clearly not. I believe the issue lies somewhere in the `if_else()` call, but am unable to figure out what I need to fix here. I came across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54173342/rasterfocal-function-replaces-edge-cells-with-na-values) about NA values at edges of the whole raster, but that is different from my case. Also, since my original raster has no NAs, it is not an issue of using `na.rm = T` or the like.

```
> summary(rast1)
        in_LULC_MODIS
Min.                0
1st Qu.             0
Median              0
3rd Qu.             0
Max.                1
NAs                0
> summary(rast2)
        in_LULC_MODIS
Min.                0
1st Qu.             0
Median              0
3rd Qu.             0
Max.                1
NAs              417
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, When the window reaches the boundaries it would have NA values and it would make virtually any function return NA. I believe padding zeros and removing NAs worked for me. Can you try this for your function?

```
rast_agg_fn <- function(x, ...){
      if_else(sum(x[!is.na(x)] == 1) >= 0.25*length(x), 1, 0) # 25% threshold
    }
```